Unable to Make Google's Dataflow Use Static IP
I'm trying to configure a Dataflow job to use a static IP for outbound connections, but it seems like the job isn't using the static IP as expected.
The objective i have is to extract data from a Microsoft SQL server and insert it into a BigQuery dataset, this is working fine if the Microsoft SQL server allows connections from any IP. What's needed is to whitelist a static IP that Dataflow will use to connect to the SQL Server for more security.
What I've done:
Network
Subnet
Serverless VPC access connector assigned to the network and subnet
Cloud NAT gateway assigned to the network
Reserved external IP
Cloud Router assigned to the NAT gateway and and Assigned to the external IP
When running the Dataflow job I set 3 parameters:
Network
Subnet
Allow External IPS: false (makes no difference if set to true)
I'm testing it against my local machine and connection is made from different google IP's everytime like 114.37.89.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.1089
Any help would be appreciated
